# Looking for a Sefer on Chagim/ Yom Tov

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, yom-tov, lomdus

I enjoy learning Rav Soloveitchik's *Hararei Kedem* and Rav Zevin's *Ha’moadim Be’halachah* to prepare for Yom Tov. Does anyone have any other recommendations for sefarim similar to these? Specifically, in Hebrew and discuss sources and analysis (lomdus) on Yomim Tovim. Could be a rec on one Chag specifically doesn't need to be like the above which are on all of them. Thanks!

Comment: Moadim uZemanim - R Moshe Shternbuch

Comment: @JoelK fyi he signs "Sternbuch"

Comment: The sefarim already mentioned are my main go-to Yom Tov sefarim of the type you describe. I understand that Hegyonei Halacha by R' Yitzchak Mirsky is well regarded, though I haven't gone through much of it myself. Chag HaAsif by R' Eliyahu Weisfish is a good one for Sukkos. The excellent Mikraei Kodesh series of sefarim by R' Moshe Harari is a thorough and highly annotated halachic compendium on the chagim, organized in the vein of Shmiras Shabbos K'hilchasah or Tefilla K'hilchasah. Though it contains lomdus, you might not consider it to be in the genre you are looking for.

Comment: I know your wrote you only want hebrew books. This sefer just came out and is a brillant analysis of the rabmam hil chometz umatzah. great for understanding the lomdoous (not al pi derech brisk but lomdous) behind the Rambam https://www.amazon.com/Seder-Night-Rambam-Chananya-Berzon/dp/B0BVT3QXJ2/ref=sr_1_27?crid=G21HFBYGGJFF&keywords=berzon&qid=1677243560&sprefix=berzon+%2Caps%2C245&sr=8-27

Comment: B'moedeah series of Rav Nevantzal

Answer (score 2):

As Joel K said, Moadim Uzmanim is the most classic.

For many years, the chiddushim of [Rav Kulefsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Moshe_Kulefsky) were published in small pamphlets that were distributed and studied across America. [Here](https://www.feldheim.com/inyanei-purim-hebrew-only) is an example of the one on Purim for sale.

Another sefer gaining a lot of popularity is Yerach L'moadim by Rav Yerucham Olshin.

In addition, some halacha sefarim have a lot of well-presented lomdus in the footnotes. A few good examples are Chazon Ovadia by Rav Ovadya Yosef, Halichos Shlomo based on the rulings of Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, and Kovetz Halachos based on the rulings and opinions of Rav Shmuel Kamenetzky.